# My Android Studio keeps ignoring Large Layout and picks Normal for ALL screens

Tags: android, layout, size, screens

I'm using the Layout Variants tool to create differents sizes for my layout.

the problem is that when i pick any large Device to preview my layout..

it keeps using the normal size

how can i force it to pick the right layout for the screen ?

by the way i already did the AndroidManifest support screens

```
    <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

but still having problems!

also my app icon looks so small too in my phone!

any idea?

Comment: try file->Invalidate caches/Restart

Comment: still , small screens and some large screens will pick the normal layout .. i'm confused here

Comment: have you designed your layouts for multi screens?

Comment: yes , what about the default layout , should i delete it and keep the normal or i keep them both ?

Comment: no need to delete default layout, you should keep that